# SQL Query for those people who turned 18 from today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and am trying to write a query that returns those contacts who have turned 18 based on the current date (today). I thought about the query below but I am unsure how to add the part where 'and date equals today'.

I appreciate that I am probably making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
    SELECT date_of_birth 
    FROM contacts
    WHERE ((DATEDIFF(Year,date_of_birth,GETDATE())>'17') AND 
(DATEDIFF(Year,date_of_birth,GETDATE())<'19'))
```

date_of_birth is greater than 17 but less than 19

Comment: why cant you use `WHERE ((DATEDIFF(Year,date_of_birth,GETDATE()) = 18)`

Comment: Do you mean everyone that turned 18 today, or everyone that *is* 18 (and have not yet turned 19) today?

Comment: Everyone who has turned 18 today.

Answer (score 1):

Just considering the Year wont fetch you the correct result, you need to consider Day and Month too. Check this out, we have been using this in our application for sometime:

```
SELECT date_of_birth 
    FROM contacts
    WHERE (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, date_of_birth,GETDATE()) / 365.25) between 17 and 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATEADD instead.  You can use negative numbers to subtract.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Also, if you have any indexes on the date_of_birth column, applying a function to that column itself in the where predicate, you may break your indexing and you'll end up with a table scan.  You can verify this by looking at the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

If your `date_of_birth` field is stored in date only format you can just add 18 Years to it and compare to today's date.

`DATEADD(YEAR,18,date_of_birth) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())`

Because `GETDATE()` gets `DATETIME` results you can just convert it to `DATE`

Here is sample code to test the logic.

```
DECLARE @date_of_birth DATE = '03/18/1996'

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 18, @date_of_birth) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
```

If you want to get all people who are 18. Means they already turned 18 but have not turned 19 yet, you can use `DATEDIFF`, in the following test, in first select statement both columns will return `'TRUE'`  but after I change DOB to `'3/17/1996'` only second case in second select returns `'TRUE'`

```
DECLARE @date_of_birth DATE = '03/18/1996'

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 18, @date_of_birth) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
        END
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, @date_of_birth, GETDATE()) = 18 THEN 'TRUE'
                ELSE 'FALSE'
        END

SET @date_of_birth = '03/17/1996'

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 18, @date_of_birth) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
        END
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, @date_of_birth, GETDATE()) = 18 THEN 'Today18'
                ELSE 'FALSE'
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple query instead of using two conditions:

```
Select date_of_birth from contacts
where datediff(yy,date_of_birth,getdate()) = 18
```